# Merge and delete case statement inside foreach

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

The query is trying to merge a relationship if the attribute inside the month node from months is in the array of strings($monthsArray). The array of strings is passed in as a parameter in cypher. If there is a match then a relationship would be created however, if there is not then the relationship between the two nodes should be removed.

I am aware that the case statement does not support MATCH and MERGE clauses however, I stuck them in below to help explain what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks!

```
MERGE (species:Reference:Species{ GUID: $reference.guid })
MATCH (months:Month) // MATCH ALL MONTHS NODES
FOREACH (month IN months)
  CASE WHEN month.name IN $monthsArray // Where $monthsArray is a parameterised string array [ "January", "March"... ]  
    THEN
      MERGE (species)-[:MEASURED_BY]->(month) 
    ELSE
      DETACH DELETE relationships((species)-[:MEASURED_BY]->(month))
```

Comment: What are the species here? Can you share the full query?

Comment: Instead of using IF-ELSE, you can delete all the relationships and then add MERGE for the given months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the `MATCH`es for the months into two sets (those you need to add, and those you need to remove) then you can blindly `FOREACH` over the two sets:

```
MERGE (species: Species { GUID: $reference.guid })
OPTIONAL MATCH (toAdd: Month) WHERE toAdd.name IN $monthsArray AND NOT ((species)-[:MEASURED_BY]->(toAdd))
WITH collect(toAdd) as toAddMonths, species
OPTIONAL MATCH (species)-[toRemove:MEASURED_BY]->(toRemoveMonth: Month) WHERE NOT toRemoveMonth.name IN $monthsArray
WITH collect(toRemove) as toRemoveRels, toAddMonths, species
FOREACH (toAdd in toAddMonths | MERGE (species)-[:MEASURED_BY]->(toAdd))
FOREACH (toRemoveRel in toRemoveRels | DELETE toRemoveRel)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes a lot more sense now! :)